# Does a fermion loop regulate effective axion QED?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, effective-field-theory, axion

I'm studying these [lectures by Falkowski](https://userswww.pd.infn.it/%7Eferuglio/Falkowski.pdf), and when talking about the [Euler-Heisenberg EFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Heisenberg_Lagrangian) he says

> consider a UV completion which is itself an effective theory. The Lagrangian contains a real scalar $h$ of mass $m_h$ coupled to photons via dimension-5 interactions
> $$\mathcal{L}_\text{UV}=-\frac{1}{4}F^2+\frac{1}{2}(\partial h)^2-\frac{m_h}{2}h^2+\frac{g}{f}hF\tilde{F}$$

Now, matching this theory to the E-H EFT is easy, but as the author specifies this still is an effective theory (as one can easily see from the presence of a nonrenormalizable operator), and I would like to find a "UUV completion".

What I'm thinking is adding a fermion coupled both to the axion and to the photon:
$$\mathcal{L}_\text{UUV}=-\frac{1}{4}F^2+\frac{1}{2}(\partial h)^2-\frac{m_h}{2}h^2+i\bar\psi\not D\psi-M_\psi\bar\psi\psi-yh\bar\psi\psi$$
All the operators in this lagrangian are renormalizable, so I should be good to go, and a photon-photon scattering should not be energy-dependant. However, I find[image]where the first two cases have the desired growth (E-H behaves badly, the axion partially corrects it) but the third one, with the fermion, seems to also grow like $E^2$!
So my question is **can I use a Lagrangian like the one I wrote to UUV-complete the axion QED?** If so, where is my mistake? If not, why, since it only contains renormalizable operators? What other choice should I make?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want the theory with the $\psi$ to reduce to $\mathcal{L}_{UV}$ when you integrate out $\psi$ or do you just want to find a renormalizable theory that reduces to E-H?

Comment: @FrodCube I would like a theory (I thought of the fermionic theory, but I'm open to other suggestions) that is a UV completion to the axion-QED (which is itself a UV completion of E-H). I know that there are lots of renormalizable theories that reduce to E-H (QED, SQED, Born-Infeld...) but I would like to use the axion-QED as an intermediate theory, provided that's possible.